# Xamarin Forms: FreshMvvM and I18n-Portable integration example

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, internationalization, freshmvvm

I am having trouble integrating the i18n-portable plugin into a FreshMvvM powered Xamarin forms app. The app keeps crashing with various exceptions, as I am not quite sure where and how to apply the changes suggested on the i18n-portable webpage (https://github.com/xleon/I18N-Portable/blob/master/README.md). Desperately looking for xamarin forms examples featuring both, freshmvvm and i18n-portable. Anyone managed to get them both running in one app?